# is there a way to convert a scratch 3.0 file into a .swf file?

Tags: mit-scratch

I tried scratch 2.0 but I use Sinhala language because l am Sri Lankan. So I can't use Sinhala in scratch 2.0 So I can't convert using scratch 2.0

Is there any other way we can convert an Sb3 file to a Swf file?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood correctly. You want to convert a Scratch project to SWF. Scratch 2.0 is not an option due to lack of language support; you feel obliged to create the project in Scratch 3.0.

I guess it should be possible to convert SB3 to SWF in two steps: first convert SB3 to SB2, then convert SB2 to SWF.
This wiki article explains both steps:
https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Porting_Scratch_Projects

#### SB3 to SB2

> Scratch user -Rex- made a .sb3 to .sb2 converter [here](https://github.com/RexScratch/sb3tosb2).
> Run sb3tosb2.py (requires Python) to run the converter.
> After the .sb2 is saved, the guides below can be followed (.mp3 files will not be converted to .wav to be used in the .sb2).

Note: it wasn't clear to me what 'guides' the last sentence refers to.

#### SB2 to SWF

> You can download an SB2 to SWF converter or use an online converter at [this site](http://junebeetle.github.io/converter/).

Note: the link above now redirects to: https://asentientbot.github.io/converter/

Comment: 'guides' simply refered to "SB2 to ___" guides below the "Porting SB3" guide in the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this as well but only because when I go to the converter on asentienbot.github.io it tells me this "Quite a few years ago, I wrote a tool to port Scratch projects to SWF files and standalone applications. It is now obsolete and unsupported."  And doesn't let me press any buttons just tells me I can download the source code.  Does this happen to you?

Comment: Please use comments (not answer) to ask more details :)

Comment: To answer your question, they're probably meaning "if you really need it, you'll use the source code to perform the conversion" which makes sense - if you're ok without it you won't go to the trouble of using the source code. It sort of gets rid of people who say "it doesn't work" even though there's a disclaimer that it's abandoned.
To clarify, yes I have the same issue. Seems like the "converter" on the site is now simply a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ruud Helderman said,  you can convert SB3 to SB2 using [this converter](https://github.com/RexScratch/sb3tosb2) made by -Rex-.
For the SB2 to SWF part, you can use the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20200808141227/https://junebeetle.github.io/converter/) to access older versions of the website.
Here, I linked the latest available version of the page.

**EDIT**: You have to download the converter since the online version redirects you to: https://asentientbot.github.io/converter/